# ruby haml unexpected ending error

Tags: ruby

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bEJW.jpg)

The _form code is:

```
    = simple_form_for @book, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
-  if @book.errors.any?
 #errors
 %p
 = @book.errors.count
 Prevented this book from saving

 %ul
 - @book.errors.full_message.each do |msg|
 %li= msg

 .panel-body
 =f.input :title, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
 =f.input :description, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}

 =f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to get much help unless you 1. spend a few seconds properly formatting your post, and 2. ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAML nesting is determined by whitespace.  You need to insert some so that the HAML interpreter knows the scope of the nests. For example, everything that's within the `form` must appear with more preceding white spaces than the `form` line does

```
    = simple_form_for @book, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
      - if @book.errors.any?
        #errors
        %p
        = @book.errors.count
        Prevented this book from saving

        %ul
        - @book.errors.full_message.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

     .panel-body
       =f.input :title, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
       =f.input :description, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}

       =f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```